# Is there any way to copy file which are modified at particular time in cmd?

Tags: windows, command-line

I am using the below command to copy all modified file day wise

```
D:\ws\xcopy *.* /s /D:04-02-2013 D:\new
```

but now i want to copy files which are modified at particular time, any have any idea how to do it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is Powershell acceptable? That is really the modern scripting engine for Windows Vista and up...

Comment: In the future please do not post across multiple sites

Answer (score 0):

[FORFILES](http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/cc753551%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) and [ROBOCOPY](http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/cc733145%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) allow a selection of files depending on the date with day accuracy. You have to specify the interval with a min and a max parameter.

This related [blog entry](http://j3ffdixon.blogspot.de/2011/03/copy-file-created-within-1-day-rename.html) might be helpful. It explains how to use `FORFILES` for copying files of the same day.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowing there's no way of doing that only using [`xcopy`](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/xcopy.mspx?mfr=true). It takes only date, not time, as an argument.

`Xcopy` is a windows program, so you might want to ask this question at for example [Stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8689170/xcopy-d-does-it-support-time-as-well-as-date) instead to get help with an alternative solution.